# How do I make the action bar fixed? UPDATED

Tags: java, android, xml

- UPDATE: I figured out the answer, but I'm too low in ranking to share my answer.

I have a simple note taking app and I'm having trouble with scrolling and the action bar. I would like for the action bar to be fixed (seen) the entire time even as I scroll down my notes or when I want to copy and paste.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/noteText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:ems="7" 
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="7dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect" >


    <requestFocus />
 </EditText>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Java Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    note = new Noteitem();
    note.setKey(intent.getStringExtra("key"));
    note.setText(intent.getStringExtra("text"));

    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
    et.setText(note.getText());
    et.setSelection(note.getText().length());
I figured out the answer.
```

I had to add the scroll view to the note taking app.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    note = new Noteitem();
    note.setKey(intent.getStringExtra("key"));
    note.setText(intent.getStringExtra("text"));

    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
    et.setText(note.getText());
    et.setSelection(note.getText().length());

    ScrollView scrollable_contents = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_note_editor, scrollable_contents);
}
```

Comment: The xml content is not important in this case. Provide codes of your Activity. (Java)

Comment: @marson I just added the java code as requested. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @marson Thank you for your suggestion! I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to add vertical scroll bars to your EditText element.

Add this:

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

So complete element will look like:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/noteText"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:ems="7" 
android:singleLine="false"
android:gravity="top"
android:lineSpacingExtra="7dp"

android:scrollbars="vertical"

android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect" >
```